# Differential of Determinant - Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential, tangent-spaces

Working from the definition:
Let $F:M \to N$ a smooth map between smooth manifolds , for each $p\in M$ the function
$$ dF_p : T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$$
is called the $\textit{differential of $F$ at $p$}$. Given $v \in T_pM$, we let $dF_p(v)$ be the derivation at $F(p)$ that acts on $f \in C^\infty(N)$ by the rule
$$dF_p(v)(f) = v(f \circ F)$$.

I need help understanding this for $F = det : M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$. I am unsure how to understand $v(f \circ F)$ - how can $v(f \circ F) \in T_p\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}$, if $v\in T_pM_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong M_2\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: for some $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}$, $A \mapsto (A(f \circ det))|_p = A\cdot c$ for some $ c \in \mathbb{R}$ . But I don't really know how to understand this as it will still be 2x2 matrix?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Try using coordinates, say  $M_2(\mathbb{R})= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{pmatrix} = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ 
and $(t = id:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R})$ for coordinates on 
$\mathbb{R}$. What is $F$ in these coordinates? In these coordinates, $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_1}}$ is an example of a $v\in T_p(M_2(\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: Also, I just noticed (and it is probably a typo) but $v(f \circ F) \in T_p\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}$ should read $v(f \circ F) \in T_{F(p)}\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}$